# Changing one progressbar changes all progressbars

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have three progress bars that should be updated to show the progress of each subject viewed in a flashcard format. Each progress bar should progress individually. I am using shared preferences to save the progress in the flashcard activity and then load that data on the activity that handles the progress bars. I have only setup my first progressbar to adjust yet all 3 progress bars adjust the same as the first.

My progressbar xml

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/introProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="4"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>

<ProgressBar
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/howToStudyProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/proceduresProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>
```

All 3 progressbars look EXACTLY alike except for the id.

Data saved in flashcard activity

```
private void savePosition(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Intro", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("Intro Progress", progress);
    editor.putInt("Intro Position", position);
    editor.putBoolean("Viewed State", viewed);
    editor.commit();
}
```

I define my progressbars in my progressbar activity

```
progressBarIntro = (ProgressBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.introProgress);
progressBarStudy = (ProgressBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.howToStudyProgress);
progressBarProcedures = (ProgressBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.proceduresProgress);
```

I load my data from my flashcard activity to my progressbar activity

```
private void loadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Intro", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    introProgressValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("Intro Progress", 0);
    introViewed = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Viewed State", false);
}
```

I setup my progressbar based on the data loaded from the flashcard activity (i have only setup the intro progress bar so there is no reason I can see for my other progressbars to be changing their progress in sync with this one)

```
private void setupProgressBars(){
if(!introViewed){
    progressBarIntro.setProgress(0);
}
if(introViewed){
    progressBarIntro.setProgress(introProgressValue + 1);
}
progressBarIntro.setMax(4);
}
```

Full .xml file showing progressbars

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

    <!--
    this goes in the above scrollview
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
     -->


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <!-- INTRODUCTION -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/introView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_no_border_selector"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="introduction"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="INTRODUCTION"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />
            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:id="@+id/introProgress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="0"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0/10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Progress"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="--"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Last Reviewed"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutview_background"
            />

        <!-- HOW TO STUDY -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/howToStudyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="howToStudy"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HOW TO STUDY"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />
            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:id="@+id/howToStudyProgress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="0"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0/10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Progress"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="--"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Last Reviewed"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutview_background"
            />

        <!-- BOARD PROCEDURES -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/boardProceduresView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="boardProcedures"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BOARD PROCEDURES"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />
            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:id="@+id/proceduresProgress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="0"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0/10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Progress"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="--"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Last Reviewed"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutview_background"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<!-- ADVIEW GOES HERE-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

I apologize for skipping a portion of my code. I am also applying a a drawable to my Progressbars

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.progress);

progressBarIntro = (ProgressBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.introProgress);
progressBarIntro.setProgressDrawable(drawable);

temp = (ProgressBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
temp.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: What's changing? Also post the rest `ProgressBar`s xmls.

Comment: All 3 progressbars are in the same .xml file and they were copied from the original one but ill paste them anways. All three progressbars are changing progress in sync with the progressBarIntro even though I have not written any code to change them.

Comment: Aren't they overlap each other because of the `layout_gravity="center"` attribute?

Comment: they are all nested in separate linearlayouts that are positioned vertically. when I view it in design mode i double clicked each one and each one showed the correct id

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `findViewById` lines for the two progress bars that you haven't written code for? Do they still show progress at run time?

Comment: paste your xml file , and you want to show all of your 3 progress bar at a time ?

Comment: If I comment out the findViewbyId for the other progressbars they don't move at all with the first progressbar. I was hoping it was overlapped in my xml file but that doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: .xml file added / I have 3 linearviews stacked on top of each other. These are used as button to open subject matter different for each one. Each subject has it's own progressbar so all three should be shown at the same time but they should not change in sync with the first.

Comment: In the spirit of the glorious history of 'have you tried turning it off and then back on again', have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: I have turned off/on android studio/restarted my phone/uninstalled the app/re-ran but I have not tried clean/rebuild. I'm doing that now.

Comment: Clean/rebuild did nothing. Still acting the same.

Comment: I feel like its a bug with android studio and not something wrong with my code. I'm updating Android Studio right now and if that doesn't work I may try a clean reinstall.

Comment: I think your code looks fine, but I haven't run it for myself. My guess is that something is corrupted and the three progress bars are sharing a common memory space, but this is just a wild guess. As a desperation measure, you could try cutting out the two other progress bars from your layout file and pasting them into a text file temporarily. Clean/rebuild again. Then put them back into your layout file, one at a time, running your app after adding back the second one. Maybe that would resolve any corrupted memory locations, but who knows.

Comment: One final idea is to try Invalidate Caches / Restart from the File menu.

Comment: Tried validate/invalidate caches. No luck. I also updated my post at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: Add a different drawable for each progressbar

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawableIntro = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.progress);
Drawable drawableTemp = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.progress);

progressBarIntro = (ProgressBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.introProgress);
progressBarIntro.setProgressDrawable(drawableIntro);

temp = (ProgressBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
temp.setProgressDrawable(drawableTemp);
```